# THREE.ArrayCamera Layers doesn’t work three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a THREE.ArrayCamera with 4 cameras and trying to make my object visible from only 1 camera. I saw I can use Layers, which work well when I have 1 camera and doesn’t work at all with Array cameras. Object isn’t visible inside all cameras, despite it has layer 1 and camera.cameras[2] has layer1 enabled. JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/h7u02jLw/

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometryCylinder, materialCylinder );
mesh.castShadow = true;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );
mesh.layers.set(1);
camera.cameras[2].layers.enable(1);
light.layers.enable(1);
    
console.log(camera.cameras[2].layers.test(mesh.layers))
    
var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00FF00});
    
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometryCylinder, material2 );
mesh2.castShadow = true;
mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `ArrayCamera` and `Layers` has only limited support.

To make the red cylinder render in only one view, it's not sufficient to just enabled the layer on the sub camera. All layers you are going to use have to be enabled on the array camera, too. The following code demonstrated this.

However, you immediately see a rendering issue since shadows are rendered on all views. That happens because the shadow map is updated only once per frame and the layer configuration of the array camera is evaluated. Since all layers are enabled, all views show the shadow of the red cylinder. Shadow maps per sub camera are not supported.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;
let mesh, mesh2;
const AMOUNT = 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  const ASPECT_RATIO = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  const WIDTH = (window.innerWidth / AMOUNT) * window.devicePixelRatio;
  const HEIGHT = (window.innerHeight / AMOUNT) * window.devicePixelRatio;

  const cameras = [];

  for (let y = 0; y < AMOUNT; y++) {

    for (let x = 0; x < AMOUNT; x++) {

      const subcamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, ASPECT_RATIO, 0.1, 10);
      subcamera.viewport = new THREE.Vector4(Math.floor(x * WIDTH), Math.floor(y * HEIGHT), Math.ceil(WIDTH), Math.ceil(HEIGHT));
      subcamera.position.x = (x / AMOUNT) - 0.5;
      subcamera.position.y = 0.5 - (y / AMOUNT);
      subcamera.position.z = 1.5;
      subcamera.position.multiplyScalar(2);
      subcamera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
      subcamera.updateMatrixWorld();
      cameras.push(subcamera);

    }

  }

  camera = new THREE.ArrayCamera(cameras);
  camera.layers.enable(1);
  camera.position.z = 3;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222244));

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
  light.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 1);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.camera.zoom = 4; // tighter shadow map
  scene.add(light);

  const geometryBackground = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
  const materialBackground = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x000066
  });

  const background = new THREE.Mesh(geometryBackground, materialBackground);
  background.receiveShadow = true;
  background.position.set(0, 0, -1);
  scene.add(background);

  const geometryCylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 1, 32);
  const materialCylinder = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  });

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometryCylinder, materialCylinder);
  mesh.castShadow = true;
  mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.layers.set(1);
  camera.cameras[2].layers.enable(1);
  //light.layers.set(1);

  var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00FF00
  });

  mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometryCylinder, material2);
  mesh2.castShadow = true;
  mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh2);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}





function onWindowResize() {

  const ASPECT_RATIO = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const WIDTH = (window.innerWidth / AMOUNT) * window.devicePixelRatio;
  const HEIGHT = (window.innerHeight / AMOUNT) * window.devicePixelRatio;

  camera.aspect = ASPECT_RATIO;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  for (let y = 0; y < AMOUNT; y++) {

    for (let x = 0; x < AMOUNT; x++) {

      const subcamera = camera.cameras[AMOUNT * y + x];

      subcamera.viewport.set(
        Math.floor(x * WIDTH),
        Math.floor(y * HEIGHT),
        Math.ceil(WIDTH),
        Math.ceil(HEIGHT));

      subcamera.aspect = ASPECT_RATIO;
      subcamera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    }

  }

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function animate() {

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
  mesh.rotation.z += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.126.1/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, at least it works somehow, all this stuff is to create a workaround for making text labels work with an array camera.